# Modificar el contenido de un dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un `dataframe` donde hay una columna llamada `Valoración` que contiene tres tipos de variables, `bien`, `mal` o `regular`. Me gustaría convertir los valores `mal`y `regular` por `no_bien` y así de esta manera trata `mal` y `regular` como un único valor.

Hago lo siguiente pero no funciona,

```
new_df.at['Valoracion']['mal'] = 'no_bien'
new_df.at['Valoracion']['regular'] = 'no_bien'

new_df = new_df.dropna()
new_df['Valoracion'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que la manera mas sencilla que se me ocurrió es con ".loc", quedando esta sencilla linea:

```
new_df.loc[new_df['Valoracion'] != 'bien'] = 'no_bien'
```

A todo en la columna 'Valoración' que es distinto de bien, le asignamos 'no_bien'

Arme el df como [Lucas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/117155/lucas-damian) en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/317302/151077)

```
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.DataFrame(['bien','mal','regular','regular','regular','bien','bien','mal'],columns=['Valoracion'])
print(new_df)

new_df.loc[new_df['Valoracion'] != 'bien'] = 'no_bien'
print("\n",new_df)
```

dando como resultado lo siguiente:

```
Antes: Valoracion
0       bien
1        mal
2    regular
3    regular
4    regular
5       bien
6       bien
7        mal

Despues:Valoracion
0       bien
1    no_bien
2    no_bien
3    no_bien
4    no_bien
5       bien
6       bien
7    no_bien
```

Answer (score 3):

Una humilde solución podría ser utilizando *lambda*. De tal manera que devuelva `bien` sí la *Valoración* es `bien`, y `no_bien` por el camino `falso`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['bien','mal','regular','regular','regular','bien','bien','mal'],columns=['Valoracion'])
```

Podemos crear una columna nueva solo para verificar que los resultados sean correctos.

```
df['foo'] = df['Valoracion'].apply(lambda x: 'bien' if x == 'bien' else 'no_bien')
```

y la salida sería asi :

```
 Valoracion | foo
----------------------
0   bien    | bien
1   mal     | no_bien
2   regular | no_bien
3   regular | no_bien
4   regular | no_bien
5   bien    | bien
6   bien    | bien
7   mal     | no_bien
```

pd: Esta solución te funcionará siempre y cuando tengas 3 valores distintos como en tu caso *bien, mal, regular*

Answer (score 3):

Edicion:
Puedes reemplazar los valores mapeando o haciendo una  correspondencia entre el valor de la columna y el valor que deberia devolver asociado a este. . En tu  caso hacemos :

"bien' le corresponde 'bien'

'mal' le corresponde 'no-bien'

'regular" le corresponde 'no-bien'

Y ejecutamos el mapeo para esa columna.  Como queremos modificar la columna hacemos que el resultado sea la misma columna.

```
 new_df['Valoracion']=new_df['Valoracion'].map({'bien':'bien','mal':'no-bien','regular':'no-bien'})
```

Comment: Las respuestas que solo tienen código sin ninguna explicación son consideradas de baja calidad. En adelante te agradeceríamos que explicases el motivo del código.

Comment: Considera dejar la edición propuesta pues estas colocando a nivel del código un texto que solo lo explica, no es que sea incorrecto pero se ve un tanto extraño

Comment: Gracias, ya edite la respuesta  realmente soy nuevo en esto y supuse que la instrucción por si sola se explicaba pero comprendo que  se debe explicar y no suponer que el que pregunta conoce de eso.

Answer (score 2):

Para esto podrias usar [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), indentificando el elemento y luego reemplazandolo con el valor que necesitas en este caso ***no_bien*** y finalmente guardas el archivo. De la siguiente forma:

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'mi_archivo.csv'
new_df = pd.read_csv(file)
new_df.loc[new_df['Valoracion'] == 'mal', "Valoracion"] = 'no_bien'
new_df.loc[new_df['Valoracion'] == 'regular', "Valoracion"] = 'no_bien'
new_df.to_csv(file, index=False)
print(new_df)
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)