# reemplazar valores en columna de acuerdo a condición en columna paralela

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, csv, jupyter

tengo una csv que estoy filtrado en pandas y es similar a lo siguiente:

```
[0]  Column1    Column2           Column3
[1]  name1      (55)Diagnostic 1  Physician1
[2]  name2      (40)Diagnostic 2  Physician2
[3]  name3      (67)Diagnostic 3  Physician3
[4]  name4      (55)Diagnostic 1  Physician5
[5]  name5      (67)Diagnostic 3  Physician5
[6]  name6      (36)Diagnostic 4  Physician7
[7]  name7      (55)Diagnostic 1  Physician2
```

Necesito reemplazar en "Column3" cualquier "Physician" por "Physician3" siempre que en la "Column2" se de "(55)Diagnostic 1".
alguna sugerencia ?

Comment: Saludos Neron, por favor visita https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour te ayudará a entender mejor cómo es que funciona el sitio. También revisa cómo preguntar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y finalmente te invito a darle una lectura https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Para que tengas claro qué ingredientes contiene una buena pregunta. Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno puedo sugerirte una respuesta que ya di anteriormente [Modificar el contenido de un dataframe - Pandas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317289/modificar-el-contenido-de-un-dataframe-pandas/317303#317303), que adaptandola para tu caso seria:

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'miArchivo.csv'
new_df = pd.read_csv(file)
new_df.loc[new_df['Column2'] == '(55)Diagnostic 1', "Column3"] = 'Physician3'
new_df.to_csv(file, index=False)

print(new_df)
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: excelente,funciono de maravilla. buscando tambien encontre un metodo con mask. gracias!